# After adding JSON data to an html option selector, how can I reference other data when selected?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm not sure of the proper terminology here so let me show my code:

```
var json = "https://example.com/";

$.getJSON(json,function(data) {
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

        $('#select').append(
            '<option value="' + data[x].name + '">' + data[x].name + '</option>'
        );
    }
});
```

The JSON Data looks like the following but has much more data:

```
[
{
    "id": "test1", 
    "name": "test1", 
    "symbol": "t1", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "55"
}, 
{
    "id": "test2", 
    "name": "test2", 
    "symbol": "t2", 
    "rank": "2", 
    "price_usd": "155"
}
]
```

Essentially when someone uses the select option and choses "test1" I want to display the other information, such as; id, symbol, rank, etc.. What's the best way to go about this dynamically and not write a bunch of if statements?

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks This isn't for anything official, just for my own use to track some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the data in the object which you're using to populate the options (`data[x].name`),
you can either filter the array of objects or change the structure so you can reference it by name,

here are some examples.

Filtering the array:

```
var dataXName = 'whatever name'
var obj = data.filter(function(x){ return x.name === dataXName })[0]
```

Mapping an object:

```
var byName = data.reduce(function(ac, x){
   return Object.assign(ac, {[x.name]:x}) 
},{})
// then you can reference the object with byName['whatever name']
```

the solutions above are plain js and don't depend on jquery.

Answer (score 1):

put the resulting `JSON` string into an object using `[JSON.parse]`[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).  Then you can use `.toggle()` or a couple of other `jQuery` fun functions and address the applicable item in the object and the values to go with.